# How to separate view from `display_field` of a custom field type?

Tags: custom-fields, add-on-development, codeigniter, fieldtype

I am implementing a custom field type which has quite a complex `display_field` function. I would like to separate the view logic and at the moment I have done the following:

```
function display_field($data) {
    ob_start();
    include('view/designer.php');
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $html;
}
```

The above works, but given that ExpressionEngine is built on CodeIgnitor which has a solid MVC architecture, what is the proper way to display a view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that's the wrong way to go about it. You want to use the load class and use the view() method. You can even pass variables to the view that can be used programmatically.

```
public function display_field($data)
{
    $vars = array(
        'data'     => $data,
        'some_var' => 'some value',
        'some_array' => array(
            '1',
            '2',
            '3'
        ),
        'some_func' => some_func()
    );

    return $this->EE->load->view('designer', $vars, TRUE);
}
```

Reference
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried using `$this->load->view` but to no avail. This is a much cleaner approach to using the PHP buffer mechanism.

Comment: This code definitely works. I use the same logic on all of my add-ons.

Comment: Yeah this certainly works! When I tried before I was just missing the `$this->EE->` part. Can I access the `lang` from within my view?

Comment: $this->EE->lang->loadfile('your_module_name');